# Native xterm mouse scrolling in tmux

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, xterm

I have decided to try tmux as GNU screen replacement and wonder if there is a way to scroll with mouse as in xterm?

It is possible to enable native xterm scrolling with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> in tmux by

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

But this does not work for mouse. I have option

```
setw -g mouse-mode on
```

in my tmux.conf, but this leads to tmux copy mode. With

```
setw -g mouse-mode off
```

mouse scroll doesn't work at all.

Is it possible to enable native xterm mouse scrolling while in tmux?

Answer (score 2):

```
setw -g mode-mouse copy-mode
```

You still have to enter copy-mode with `Shift + PageUp`